# How to add error messages for DateValidation?

Tags: yii2

In my model I use DateValidation

```
['date_birthday', 'date', 'format' => 'd.m.yy', 'min' => '01.01.1900', 'max' => date('d.m.yy'), 'tooSmall'=>'The date is from past. Try another','tooBig' => 'The date is from future. Try another', 'message' => 'Try to input the date'],
```

In view I call the widget

```
 <?php echo $form->field($modelForm, 'date_birthday')->widget(\kartik\date\DatePicker::classname(), [
                        'type' => \kartik\date\DatePicker::TYPE_COMPONENT_APPEND,
                        'pickerButton' => false,
                        'options' => [
                            'placeholder' => '',
                        ],
                        'pluginOptions' => [
                            'format' => 'dd.mm.yyyy',
                            'autoclose' => true,
                            'showMeridian' => true,
                            'startView' => 2,
                            'minView' => 2,
                        ]
                    ]) ?>
```

It checks for min and max dates, but show no error message. I think its because of different date formats in model and view. How to fix it?

Comment: How do you know it checks for min and max dates ?

Comment: When I input dates out of range it doesn't save

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you submit form you will see error messages. According to this issue https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/7745 yii2 have not client-side validations of date

You can enable ajax validation. Add in create and update action before if statement

```
if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
    Yii::$app->response->format = yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    return ActiveForm::validate($model);
}
```

And add use `yii\widgets\ActiveForm;` on the top of controller class. In your `_form.php` file enable ajax for whole form

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
]); ?>
```

, or for the field only

```
<?php echo $form->field($model, 'date_birthday', ['enableAjaxValidation' => true])->widget(\kartik\date\DatePicker::classname(), [
...
```

Also, you can add plugin options for limit date with startDate and endDate (https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#startdate)

```
 <?php echo $form->field($model, 'date_birthday', ['enableAjaxValidation' => true])->widget(\kartik\date\DatePicker::classname(), [
                    'type' => \kartik\date\DatePicker::TYPE_COMPONENT_APPEND,
                    'pickerButton' => false,
                    'options' => [
                        'placeholder' => '',
                    ],
                    'pluginOptions' => [
                        'format' => 'dd.mm.yyyy',
                        'autoclose' => true,
                        'showMeridian' => true,
                        'startView' => 2,
                        'minView' => 2,
                        'startDate' => '01.01.1900',
                        'endDate' => date('d.m.Y'),
                    ]
                ]) ?>
```

Comment: for correct comparing you may use other format, such as Y-m-d. Yii compare date with simple '<' and '>' [DateValidator.php](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/validators/DateValidator.php#L266). You can override this behavior or use before and after validate event for change format of date